# from utf8 to latin1

Tags: dart, utf-8, decode

I have an utf-8 string like this:

```
=C3=A0=C3=A8=C3=AC=C3=B2=C3=B9
```

I need to decode the string to latin1. The expected result is:

```
àèìòù
```

This is what I tried without success:

```
utf8.decode(stringData.runes.toList())
```

Comment: You should move the solution to an answer and mark it accepted. That will help future searcher find this. You should likely change the title, however. Your `latin1` step is not helping (at least the way you've written it). you're just turning quoted-printable into Unicode via utf-8. I don't believe the latin1 step is doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.
Thanks to @lenz comment and the js function found [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/quoted-printable/blob/master/src/quoted-printable.js) I solved with this function:

```dart
String decodeQuotedPrintable(String input) {
  return input
      // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6.7, rule 3:
      // “Therefore, when decoding a `Quoted-Printable` body, any trailing white
      // space on a line must be deleted, as it will necessarily have been added
      // by intermediate transport agents.”
      .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\t\x20]$', multiLine: true), '')
      // Remove hard line breaks preceded by `=`. Proper `Quoted-Printable`-
      // encoded data only contains CRLF line endings, but for compatibility
      // reasons we support separate CR and LF too.
      .replaceAll(RegExp(r'=(?:\r\n?|\n|$)', multiLine: true), '')
      // Decode escape sequences of the form `=XX` where `XX` is any
      // combination of two hexidecimal digits. For optimal compatibility,
      // lowercase hexadecimal digits are supported as well. See
      // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6.7, note 1.
      .replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'=([a-fA-F\d]{2})'), (match) {
        var codePoint = int.parse(match[1], radix: 16);
        return String.fromCharCode(codePoint);
      });
}
```

and with this code:

```dart
var output = decodeQuotedPrintable(input);
output = utf8.decode(latin1.encode(input));
```